# Does the Product of conjugates of some subgroups commutes with all elements of another subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $U,V \le G$ abelian subgroups such that $V$ is normal and $G$ be finite, does it hold that for $v \in V$ we have
$$ 
 u \cdot \left( \prod_{u' \in U} v^{u'} \right) = \left( \prod_{u' \in U} v^{u'} \right) \cdot u
$$
for each $u \in U$?

Comment: I am not sure $\prod_{u'\in U}v^{u'}$ is well-defined. While $U$ and $V$ may be abelian, why must the $U$-conjugates of a particular element $v\in V$ commute?

Comment: you are right! I was confronted with such a situation in the context of normal subgroups, but tried to formulate the question as general as possible, and thereby forget that this is necessary! I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does hold. Recall that $zx^yz^{-1}=zyxy^{-1}z^{-1}=(zy)x(zy)^{-1}=x^{zy}$ and $x^yz^y=(xz)^y$. Therefore...
$$u \cdot \left( \prod_{u' \in U} v^{u'} \right) \cdot u^{-1} = \prod_{u' \in U} v^{uu'} =  \prod_{u' \in U} v^{u'}$$
The reason this last equality holds is that as $u'$ runs through $U$, the product $uu'$ runs through $U$ (left multiplication is 1-1 and onto). Thus we can re-index and get the desired result.

**Edit:** I originally said, you don't need most of the assumptions. It is true that $U$ doesn't need to be abelian (just a finite subgroup will do). However, $v$'s conjugates needs to commute each other (well, at least the conjugates you get when conjugating by $U$). But your assumption that $V$ is normal guarantees that $v$'s entire conjugacy class is contained in $V$ and $V$ is assumed to be abelian so $v$'s conjugates *do* commute with each other.

Actually, without the assumption $v$'s conjugates commute with each other, the product wouldn't even be well-defined!

Comment: in the end it is so simple!

Comment: Glad to help! By the way, if you study group representation theory, you'll see this reindex "trick" used over and over again. For example, the above calculation looks a lot like what comes up when trying to determine the center of a group algebra.

Comment: guess I am well prepared now for group representation theory ;)